# Using different blogs in the same wordpress

Tags: wordpress, blogs

We want to have multiple blogs in one wordpress enviroment. Namely different categories like life and health. They should have the same look and a user should be able to switch between blog topics.

Is it recommended that I have multiple installations of wordpress so that I have a seperate cms for each blog? Currently its just a user that handles all the content, however in the future there could be a writer that should only be allowed to write into one topic/blog.

Whats the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The best way provided that in the future multiple writers will add content, is to create a multisite wordpress plateform using the same theme.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

If you want to specialize each blog in one theme like live and health you can create one blog for each theme. for instance :
yourdomain.com/life
yourdomain.com/health

But you can also create one blog and use the category system of wordpress in order to create the universe, which is more simpler and faster to setup.

The best choice will depend on the number of content you want to publish, the restrictions for each writer,...